# await used outside an async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on react + firestore 9 for a project and i've been looking at a way of retrieving data to display on my application. Thing is I see a lot of people recommending this syntax:

```js
import firebase, { db } from 'path/to/firebase';
import {collection, getDocs, getDoc, query, doc,  addDoc, deleteDoc, updateDoc} from "firebase/firestore";

// CONSULTA
const result = await getDocs(query(collection(db, 'persons')));
```

My question is about the await outside an async function, I allways get the same error that I solve by creating an async function to wrap the await like so:

```js
import firebase, { db } from 'path/to/firebase';
import {collection, getDocs, getDoc, query, doc,  addDoc, deleteDoc, updateDoc} from "firebase/firestore";

// CONSULTA
const result = async() => { 
 const foo = await getDocs(query(collection(db, 'persons')));
};
```

So; is there something I can do to make it work outside the async function, or am I doomed for eternity to wrap awaits in async functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not wrong await can be only used in async function. But you can use .then(() => {}) and add logic in it, you will be sure that the code will be triggered after the promise and your data will be defined.

In your case I guess you want something like this

```
getDocs(query(collection(db), 'persons')))
.then((foo) => {
  // do something foo is defined
  // code outside this scope will be triggered before the .then 
})
.catch(err => console.log("there is an error", err));
```

Remember that async function will always return a promise and so even you you wrap your code inside async function you will have to use a .then() at the end. So maybe you want to stay with .then instead because you don't need async function to use .then

Comment: I've also seen that .then works for async functions. But I can't figure out why everybody recommends that syntax if you need to add the .then everytime, you can even see it on the firebase official docs, they present to you this get function: 


const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
});

Comment: @PedroMontesinosNavarro As I said an async function return a promise anyway so when you are using await it your code become synchrone only inside the promise, we recommand to use .then() because it avoid this kind of confusion, also it's easier to debug with tools.

You can use async await but just remember that if you want to do something after this function you will have to add a .then() anyway.

await can be nicer to read since you directly know you are waiting for someting

Comment: I think I understand now, they don't include the .then() in those code examples to make the code briefer and simpler so it can be easier to understand, right?

Comment: @PedroMontesinosNavarro yes it make the code seem to be synchronous and so easier to read and to explain. But async await can be very tricky ;)